# Unresponsive boot after dual-boot (win10) install / freeze at motherboard logo

Tags: boot, freeze

Win10 / Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS amd64
3700x
Gigabyte Aorus Elite REV1.0 / BIOS F34

Hi,

I'll try to compact my issue and what I've carried out/found trying to fix my problem over the last 3 days.

I had a manjaro install in dual-boot with Win10 previously. I removed this install with diskpart by selecting the disk and cleaning (removed because of RDRAND "funky smelling output" - although note, Manjaro was not the cause of the RDRAND issue). I then realised the bootloader was still present so I assigned the EFI a drive letter in cmd, navigated to the bootloader and removed this. After, I reformatted all disks and removed all partitions and the EFI altogether, then proceeded with a fresh install of Win10 and updated my BIOS with the latest firware to remove the RDRAND issue previosuly preventing manjaro boot and subsequent installs of other distros.

From here, I presumed my issues had been fixed and could proceed with a clean dual-boot win10/ubuntu. (win10 ISO install was smooth and now boots fine after removing manjaro from EFI) Grub now does show, but freezes at motherboard logo screen and doesnt go past this.

I've ran all options from the grub to test file system, bootloader etc. I've wiped multiple drives Ubuntu and other distro I've tried, multiple times.

Are there logs that I could access from the grub that would help?

EDIT: added 'nomodeset' in the grub edit on the linux line. - No change after reboot.

added after the initrd /initrd.img -
echo 'Loaded Linux kernel...'
sleep 5

no change.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The reason I mention the RDRAND issue was because this was somthing that had previously stopped me from dual booting / single booting any linux distro. As I mention above, I believe I've fixed this with the explination I've outlined in my OP however, have mentioned this in case this is relevant to the current problem I'm having. Again, A firmware update rolled out by the motherboard manufacturer has fixed this. 

I have wiped all the drives multiple times and have started with fresh installs as I said. Could you please tell me what further details you would like?

Comment: I have included all of my attempted solutions to the problem that I'm currently having - which is the frozen motherboard logo after selecting Ubuntu in the grub screen. To further provide you with more information around the frozen boot, I'm currently trying to find out how to access log files and will post these ASAP.